# Ionic failed to build for Android, JAVA_HOME invalid, failed to run java -version

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, java-home

I already tried to set my `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`
and the path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your screenshot says that your `JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre` Can you recheck your `JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

The goal of what you are asking to do is to install java and let some other program find java by setting two Windows variables JAVA_HOME and path to point to the java directory and the java executable/program file directory respectively. I assume you are using windows because of some of the clues you gave.  You first need to download java, get the JDK and not the JRE version. Download from here[java](http://java.com/en/download/faq/develop.xml) then set the two variables, find mycomputer icon or maybe its called this pc and right click find properties click advanced system settings, environment variables there you go, put in the variable and value for both JAVA_HOME and path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had solved it.
The cause of problem changing the path when installing jdk. Changed jre path to

```
../jdk1.8.0/jre
```

the right is for example:

```
../java/jdk1.8.0
../java/jre8
```

or change nothing.

So, if you are sure that `JAVA_HOME` path is right, try to reinstall jdk and change nothing before complete.